# jQuery slider carousel stop at end

Tags: jquery, carousel, slide

All right. I am building a custom carousel with some simple javascript and css3. It is working okay so far. However. When I continue clicking next button(when slider is at end), it continues without a stop function (so everything will become out of focus and messy). [I have created a small fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dz19gdpo/)

The code its all about is minified down to following:

```
function nextSlide(){
    counter++;
    var slideWidth = articleWidth*counter;
    var articles = $('#slider article.boxed').length;
    //Magic with css3
    $('.carousel>div').css('-webkit-transform', 'translate3d('+-slideWidth+'px, 0px, 0px)');
    $('.carousel>div').css('-ms-transform', 'translate3d('+-slideWidth+'px, 0px, 0px)');
    $('.carousel>div').css('transform', 'translate3d('+-slideWidth+'px, 0px, 0px)');
}
```

I have tried calculating the stop pos in terms of width/number of slides(articles), but it will get to buggy, I guess, and I am looking for something fluid that will work with my css responsive (shown in the fiddle). Any suggestions? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution with help from jQuery forums. Decided to post it here if any visitor needs to know how to do it :)

Complete code:

```
var counter         = 0,
    articleWidth    = 350, //Fixed width of articles, divs etc
    articles = $('#slider article.boxed').length;//Length of articles, divs etc.

function nextSlide(){
        var va = Math.floor($('.carousel').width() / articleWidth)+1;
        if (counter < articles - va) {
            counter++;
            var slideWidth = articleWidth*counter;
            //Magic with css3
            $('.carousel>div').css('-webkit-transform', 'translate3d('+-slideWidth+'px, 0px, 0px)');
            $('.carousel>div').css('-ms-transform', 'translate3d('+-slideWidth+'px, 0px, 0px)');
            $('.carousel>div').css('transform', 'translate3d('+-slideWidth+'px, 0px, 0px)');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

hope the below link help you.

http://jsfiddle.net/YFgAM/

```
$('.block-13 .show-more.prev').click(function () {
var last = $('.block-13 .list li:last-child');
last.remove();
$('.block-13 .list').filter(':not(:animated)').prepend(last);

$('.block-13 .list').filter(':not(:animated)').css({
    right: '+=' + width
});

$('.block-13 .list').filter(':not(:animated)').animate({
    right: '-=' + width
});
```

});

Comment: Hmm... Your idea is good, but in my case I do not want my carousel to be infinite :)

Answer (score 1):

in your `nextSlide` function you can do something like this:

```
function nextSlide(){
    if (counter + 1 == $('.carousel > div > article').length) {
        return;
    }

    counter++;

    //--------
}
```

[Updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dz19gdpo/1/)

Comment: Good idea. Though this will not work. I tried this approach too. If you resize the slider, you can see that it is still failing :)